# iBeacons using a user's mobile to trigger a digital sign

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am trying to figure out a way to use iBeacons to trigger a physical Digital Screen.  Has anyone done this or seen this?

What I would like to do is when a customer gets close to a digital screen an iBeacon would be triggered and would load to a digital tv screen an ad hosted on a website.  I know you can do this to the phone screen, but can the trigger load content to digital signage?  If so what would be needed?  I already have an app that is triggering API calls.  I assume we need some kind of computer hooked to the screen that receives the trigger and then displays content, but having a hard time wrapping my head around what is needed and have failed to see this anyplace.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You question is quite broad, but essentially you will need an app on the phone to send a message to a server somewhere and then the server would notify the device connected to the screen to take whatever action you wanted

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of architectures that would support this.  Below is a simple approach that I have prototyped before:

- Make an electronic billboard display out of a computer or tablet that has:

  1. Internet connectivity to refresh an ad from a remote web app.
  2. A Web Browser that opens to the add display URL in the web app mentioned above.
  3. Transmits as a beacon with a known identifier. You can make the tablet or computer send a beacon transmission with the onboard bluetooth interface, or you can simply plug in a [USB bluetooth beacon](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/radbeacon-usb-2) to an open port.
- Build a server-side app that does the following:

  1. Has a number of configurable advertisements that display in a web browser.
  2. Has a mapping of user identifiers to advertisements (basically the logic of what users are shown what ads)
  3. Exposes a web service to register new mobile app installations that provide the user identifier, along with any user info (name, address, etc.) needed to target ads.
  4. Exposes a web service to accept notifications of what nearby users have detected the beacon.
  5. Automatically refreshes the advertisement to be targeted to whatever user is nearby, or some default otherwise.
- Build a mobile app that:

  1. Upon installation, calls the web service on the server-side app mentioned above to send the user info (name, address, etc.) needed to target advertisements.
  2. Detects the beacon mentioned above using CoreLocation (iOS) or the [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) (Android).
  3. When the beacon is detected, calls the web service on server-side app with the user identifier to tell it that the user is nearby.